# Regex to match which is not between specific special characters

Tags: regex-negation

I need a regex for below scenario
I have below strings from the below strings I need to match which is not in between /* and */ and regex need to match between hello and ;

please let me know how to do that

String 1:
/*hello
how are you;*/

hello
how are you;

Comment: Try `^hello\show\sare\syou;$`

Comment: Description : 1 - `^` is for the first of the string. 2 - `$` is for the end of the string. Also you can don't use them if you don't want just use the pattern without `^` and `$`.